# LyX: Vertical align in table with large image

Tags: tables, graphics, lyx, vertical-alignment

I have a table containing some text as well an image that is higher than the text. Although vertical alignment is set to `top`, the text is still at the bottom:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Edit] I think for these solutions to work, you must set your columns to fixed widths!*

## Solution 1

Put the cursor directly before the image and go to **Insert > Formatting > Vertical Space...**.

Under *Spacing*, select `Custom`. Under *Value*, enter `0`, or whatever you'd like the space above the picture to be. Click *Ok*. The table now behaves as desired:

[image]

## Solution 2

Directly before the image, create a TeX box (for example by hitting Ctrl+L) and write `\vspace{0pt}` (or whatever you'd like the space above the picture to be) inside it. The table now behaves as desired:

[image]

## Tip

In case you want to insert another picture below the first one, you can also use one of these techniques to create a reasonable spacing between the two pictures:

[image]

## Result:

[image]